# How to use Finalize() and Dispose() on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, destructor, dispose, idisposable, finalize

I can't get to delete an object and the reference to it.
After using the Finalize() method on an object and using the GarbageCollector Collect() method, i am still able to call the object and see its attributes.
I would like to see two simple examples of how to use these two methods to understand how to correctly use them.

Comment: since this is not a tutorial service, why dont you show how you are   implementing them as a starting point

Comment: Microsoft was kind enough to provide examples for both: [Object.Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Idisposable.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx).